# Getting date from core data swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mobile

Am trying to display the timestamp a new post is made on a label but in don't seem to get around with it please help

Have tried using NSDate() but am getting an abort() error from the Appdelegate

Comment: How are you fetching this date?

Comment: Just want to know if there is a way to get the timestamp of the post from the database(core data)

Comment: What type of timestamp? Creation date?

Comment: Alright, check out my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to add a property to the entity called `creationDate` and sets its value on insert.

```
@interface YourEntity : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDate *creationDate;
@end

@implementation YourEntity
@dynamic creationDate; 

- (void)awakeFromInsert
{
    [super awakeFromInsert];

    self.creationDate = [NSDate date];
}
@end
```

Then, just access the property when you need it.

Comment: Can you give it in swift